# Retrieve autocomplete input value from child component

Tags: reactjs

I am using Mosh Hamedani's autocomplete component and adding a search button in App.js to do something. My problem here is I cannot get the child to autocomplete component value in the parent component. I am passing an onClick event as props to the child component and hope the child component callback function can update the search term in the parent, so the search button can get the value. My sandbox is here https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-frost-1xo45?file=/src/App.js. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: I don't know who "Mosh Hamedani" is, but this looks like a pretty sloppy React component.  But more to the point, it doesn't look like it does much with the selected value other than set its own internal state.  You're likely better off with a more popular autocomplete component, or writing/modifying your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing your onClick handlers.

The Autocomplete component has an internal `onClick` method that sets internal state when the user clicks the internal input element. This looks like the equivalent to what you need - it "finalizes" the user's selection (though this Autocomplete component is pretty bare bones). It looks like you never use that method; instead, you call `this.props.onClick`, or the handler you passed as props that updates your parent component state, as the click handler to the internal input element. What you need to do is call your `this.props.onClick' method when the user finalizes their choice, like so:

```
// in the Autocomplete component...
onClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      filteredSuggestions: [],
      showSuggestions: false,
      userInput: e.currentTarget.innerText
    });
    this.props.onClick(e.currentTarget.innerText);
  };

/* ... */

render () {
  /* ... */
  // the input element now calls the internal onClick, seen above, which only then calls our props onClick method
  return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <input
          type="search"
          onChange={onChange}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
          value={userInput}
          onClick={this.onClick}
        />
        {suggestionsListComponent}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Here's [the updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-gauss-0spfg).

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! I tried to add  this.props.onClick(e.currentTarget.value);  to onChange, onKeyPress event but onClick handler and it didn't work. So I gave up.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: You should ask yourself, "why did I add it to onChange?" onChange is an internal method (to the Autocomplete component) that handles changes in the internal input and keeps track of intermediate state before the user finalizes their choice. It makes sense to add your onClick handler to the key event handler but not to the onChange method.